# Orange Colur highlighted area is coming when clicking on a button in the webview

Tags: javascript, android, svg, webview

in the webview iam loading a url(check.svg)(below code for svg 19 button) after loading into the webview iam clicking on that button with in the webview orange colour highlighted area is coming just above to the clicking area.

my code contains svg and javascript code

svg code for eg

// this will display abutton with num 19

```
 <!ENTITY GroupAC  "  <!-- ENTITY -->
 <g transform='translate(0,0)'>
 <use   xlink:href='#temp' transform='translate(690,30),scale(.82,.87)' opacity='1'    /> 
 <use   class='19ani'   xlink:href='#19' transform='translate(682,0)'  opacity='1'    />   
 <rect id='19' onclick='skfServeIR(evt,1)'   fill='#009900'  x='710' y='255' width='35'    height='17' opacity='.01'/>   

  //javascript code for above button 
  function skfServeIR(evt,flag) 
{
var currentTab = evt.target;
var parentGroup = currentTab.parentElement; 
var areaGroup = currentTab.parentElement;         
evt.target.style.webkitTapHighlightColor="transparent";
skfZoom(evt,1); setInterval(function () { skfUnZoom(evt,1); }, 300);
while (parentGroup.id != "Layer_1") parentGroup = parentGroup.parentElement; 
// Auto Adjusted
while (areaGroup.id.split("-")[0] != "toptab") areaGroup = areaGroup.parentElement; 
// Auto Adjusted
var endDeviceID = areaGroup.id.split("-")[2];
var endDeviceAction = currentTab.id; // tmp
skf_executeScriptUnique('appliances',endDeviceID,endDeviceAction,' ',' ',' ');
}
```

this code is working without orange colour highlighted ara after clicking on button 19 in the googlechrome.  The problem is raising in webview only.

i tried all the possible ways given in stackoverflow its not working for me.

i have been struggling from past 10 days please help me.